# Is it possible that inhaling copper vapor, in some form, can help in treating a bacterial or viral infection of the lung?

Tags: infection, bacteria, lungs, metal

There are many studies showing the [antimicrobial properties of copper](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Antimicrobial_properties_of_copper). 
Based on these properties, is it possible that inhaling copper vapor, in some form, can help in treating a bacterial or viral infection of the lung?

Comment: have you done any research on inhaling metals?

Comment: Copper poisoning is the first hit if you google inhaling+copper.